# python merge multiple xmls to single CSV

Tags: python, xml, csv, merge

Here's a snippet from a script I'm trying to put together to make my life easier. I have a bunch of XML files from different API sources. They have different items in them and different amount of fields. What they do all have in common is a common field like "clientid".

What I want to do is end up with a CSV that has the combined headers of all the XMLs with their corresponding data. So i need to be able to make sure that all the info from the "clientid" of 12345 adds onto the end of the row for the client id of the same name in the "itemid" pull

item data:

```
<item>
<id>99899</id>
<client-id>12345</client-id>
```

part of script:

```
def parseXML():
    ### Parse XML and convert to CSV ###
    #Get XML Source #
    tree = ET.fromstring(getdata)
    # open a file for writing
    xmlTest01 = open('xmlTest01.csv', 'w')
    # create the csv writer object
    csvwriter = csv.writer(xmlTest01)
    item_head = []

    count = 0
    for member in tree.findall('item'):
                    item = []
                    if count == 0:
                                    id = member.find('id').tag
                                    item_head.append(id)
                                    clientid = member.find('client-id').tag
                                    item_head.append(clientid)

                    id = member.find('id').text
                    item.append(id)
                    clientid = member.find('client-id').text
                    item.append(clientid)
                    csvwriter.writerow(item)
    xmlTest01.close()
```

The next set of data has this in it:

```
<client>
<id>12345</id>
<name>Clients name</name>
<current type="boolean">true</current>
<status>good</status>
```

So I want to check the row in the previous set of data for the clientid of the same and then add name, current and status to the end of that row.

Any ideas on the best way to do this? I have about 5-7 of these types of files to merge. Should I be trying to combine the files first before converting them to CSV? This might be ok if they all had similar content but they dont.

Desired output which combines values of both xml files:

```
id,clientid,name,current,status
99899,12345,Clients name,true,good
```

Comment: Can you post a fuller input XML (with root tags) and not snippets for a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Desired results of csv output might be helpful and illustrate your textual description.

Comment: please read [MCVE]

Comment: @Parfait ok. I'll try and simplify it shortly and update the question with a more simplified working example. the real data I can't post as is. So I'd need to modify it all and some of the xml files are quite large. the root tags for the first is simply <items> </items> and the second is <clients> </clients>  then its just a few hundred of what I put up there with different ids and field contents. I'm pulling live data for this so ill need to make an example files to post here with a working script that uses them too. it works now with just one xml at a time. But i dont know how to combine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider iterating across the three files and conditionally check for client ids. Parse xml values to a list that you write to csv file:

```
import csv
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET 

def parseXML():
    projecttree = ET.parse('projects.xml')
    clienttree = ET.parse('clients.xml')
    teamtasktree = ET.parse('teammembers.xml')

    projectroot = projecttree.getroot()
    clientroot = clienttree.getroot()
    teamtaskroot = teamtasktree.getroot()

    data = []
    for i in projectroot.iter('project'):
        for j in clientroot.iter('client'):
            clientid = i.find('client-id').text
            if clientid == j.find('id').text:
                data.append(i.find('id').text)
                data.append(j.find('id').text)
                data.append(j.find('name').text)
                data.append(j.find('active').text)
                data.append(i.find('name').text)
                data.append(i.find('active').text)
                data.append(i.find('billable').text)
                data.append(i.find('bill-by').text)
                data.append(i.find('hourly-rate').text)
                data.append(i.find('budget').text)
                data.append(i.find('over-budget-notification-percentage').text)
                data.append(i.find('created-at').text)
                data.append(i.find('updated-at').text)
                data.append(i.find('starts-on').text)
                data.append(i.find('ends-on').text)
                data.append(i.find('estimate').text)
                data.append(i.find('estimate-by').text)
                data.append(i.find('notes').text)
                data.append(i.find('cost-budget').text)

        cnt = 1     
        for tm in teamtaskroot.iter('team_members'):
            for item in tm.iter('item'):                
                if item.find('cid').text == clientid and cnt <= 3:
                    data.append(item.find('full_name').text)
                    data.append(item.find('cost_rate').text)
                cnt += 1

        cnt = 1
        for tk in teamtaskroot.iter('tasks'):
            for item in tk.iter('item'):                
                if item.find('cid').text == clientid and cnt <= 2:
                    data.append(item.find('task_id').text)
                    data.append(item.find('total_hours').text)
                cnt += 1

    with open('Output.csv', 'w') as f:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(f, lineterminator = '\n')
        csvwriter.writerow(['Pid', 'Clientid', 'ClientName', 'ClientActive', 'ProjectName', 'ProjectActive',
                            'Billable', 'BillBy', 'HourlyRate', 'Budget', 'OverbudgetNotificationPercentage',
                            'CreatedAt', 'UpdatedAt', 'StartsOn', 'EndsOn', 'Estimate', 'EstimateBy',
                            'Notes', 'CostBudget', 'TeammemberName1', 'CostRate1', 'TeammemberName2', 'CostRate2',
                            'TeammemberName3', 'CostRate3', 'TaskId1', 'TotalHours1', 'TaskId2', 'TotalHours2'])
        csvwriter.writerow(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parseXML()
```

**Output**

```
Pid,Clientid,ClientName,ClientActive,ProjectName,ProjectActive,Billable,
BillBy,HourlyRate,Budget,OverbudgetNotificationPercentage,CreatedAt,
UpdatedAt,StartsOn,EndsOn,Estimate,EstimateBy,Notes,CostBudget,TeammemberName
1,CostRate1,TeammemberName2,CostRate2,TeammemberName3,CostRate3,
TaskId1,TotalHours1,TaskId2,TotalHours2
11493770,4708336,AFB,true,Services - Consulting - AH,true,true,Project,
421.28,16.0,80.0,2016-08-16T03:22:51Z,
2016-08-16T03:22:51Z,,,16.0,project,Random 
notes,,BobR,76.0,BobR,76.0,BobR,76.0,6357137,0.0,6357138,0.0
```

Comment: Hey... I fell asleep earlier. sorry for getting back to you late. I think this is what I want actually! Let me try and integrate it. WIll report back. Thanks so far!!

Comment: Its working good and cleaner than my original path. I can build from here.  thanks man. Realllllly appreciate it!!

Comment: Great to hear! Glad I could help.

Comment: hate to bother you again sir. You helped me with joining the other large XML together. For each entry in that XML I'm injecting the client id and the project id.  HERE you helped by showing me how to relate id's from two sources and then pull fields from each source into a single CSV.  any chance you could update this with using the third resource?  I've tried to follow your example but im getting blank CSV's when I add a third source. I'm not sure if its because there are multiple matches for the same client id in the third source.  this is the last bit I need for this script.

Comment: What is your desired csv data file? Specifically, what are the fields you need captured from all three sources? Should there be only one row per id as the team_members and task xml has multiple elements per id?

Comment: I updated the question with more info (maybe too much) it looks more daunting than it is im sure. Seriously thanks for the time.

Comment: There may be a better route which I almost added as a second answer even had ready and tested which requires no looping (but I didn't want to confuse you), using XSLT (the XML transformation language which I love coding in) which Python's lxml module can run. XSLT can directly transform xml to csv!

Comment: hmmm... If theres no looping, than technically that makes it a bit more efficient no? im interested. The code in this script wont change much once its set. I'm still trying to wrap my head around how Element tree works fully. But if you think the other solution is more elegant, I'll learn how you did it so I understand what it does and add to it. I have used element tree in previous functions to inject pid and cid. I assume that won't need to change with XSLT and lxml since the main parsing function uses the final results of the xmls. etc.. thoughts? What do you think the best method is?

Comment: I added the full script I'm using so you can get an idea of where I'm at. See the last link in the question. It's messy right now due to testing(still learning). Had intentions of cleaning it up later after its working.. heh.

Comment: I was reading up on the XSLT.  Didnt even know it existed. It's pretty cool. The online converters work surprisingly well. I wouldn't know where to begin to implement that into the script. But I'll definitely have use for this at some point eleswhere. Good to know something like this is out there!

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special purpose transformation language that can directly transform XML to CSV even parsing from other XML files using its `document()` function. Python's [lxml](http://lxml.de/) module can process XSLT 1.0 scripts. Be sure all three xmls reside in same directory.

**XSLT** Script *(save as .xsl file --a special .xml file-- to be called below in Python)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" method="text" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/projects">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:text>Pid,Clientid,ClientName,ClientActive,ProjectName,ProjectActive,Billable,BillBy,HourlyRate,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>Budget,OverbudgetNotificationPercentage,CreatedAt,UpdatedAt,StartsOn,EndsOn,Estimate,EstimateBy,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>Notes,CostBudget,TeammemberName1,CostRate1,TeammemberName2,CostRate2,TeammemberName3,CostRate3,</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text>TaskId1,TotalHours1,TaskId2,TotalHours2&#xa;</xsl:text>      
      <xsl:apply-templates select="project"/>      
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="project">    
    <xsl:variable name="clientid" select="client-id"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(id, ',')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="delimiter"><xsl:text>&quot;,&quot;</xsl:text></xsl:variable>

    <xsl:for-each select="document('clients.xml')/clients/client[id=$clientid]/*
                                   [local-name()='id' or local-name()='name' or local-name()='active']">
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
      <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>      
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:value-of select="concat(',',name,',',active,',',billable,',',bill-by,',',hourly-rate,',',budget,',',
                                 over-budget-notification-percentage,',',created-at,',',updated-at,',',starts-on,',',ends-on,',',
                                 estimate,',',estimate-by,',',notes,',',cost-budget,',')"/>        

    <xsl:for-each select="document('teammembers.xml')/root/team_members/item[cid=$clientid]/*
                                   [local-name()='full_name' or local-name()='cost_rate']">
      <xsl:if test="position() &lt; 5">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />      
        <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:for-each select="document('ClientItems_teammembers.xml')/root/tasks/item[cid=$clientid]/*
                                   [local-name()='task_id' or local-name()='total_hours']">
      <xsl:if test="position() &lt; 5">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
          <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>

    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Python** script *(transforming projects.xml and reading in other two in XSLT)*

```
import lxml.etree as ET

def transformXML():
    dom = ET.parse('projects.xml')
    xslt = ET.parse('XSLTscript.xsl')

    transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
    newdom = transform(dom)

    with open('Output.csv'),'w') as f:
        f.write(str(newdom))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    transformXML()
```

**Output**

```
Pid,Clientid,ClientName,ClientActive,ProjectName,ProjectActive,Billable,
BillBy,HourlyRate,Budget,OverbudgetNotificationPercentage,CreatedAt,
UpdatedAt,StartsOn,EndsOn,Estimate,EstimateBy,Notes,CostBudget,TeammemberName
1,CostRate1,TeammemberName2,CostRate2,TeammemberName3,CostRate3,
TaskId1,TotalHours1,TaskId2,TotalHours2
11493770,4708336,AFB,true,Services - Consulting - AH,true,true,Project,
421.28,16.0,80.0,2016-08-16T03:22:51Z,
2016-08-16T03:22:51Z,,,16.0,project,Random 
notes,,BobR,76.0,BobR,76.0,BobR,76.0,6357137,0.0,6357138,0.0,
```

Comment: dude!! you're awesome. Ive spent so much time over the years helping people in the unreal gamedev community, this is the first time soeone has spent a good amount of time trying to help ME. I want to send you a puppy or something! testing the first option now. logging the second for study later.  For the first option, if do say ten tasks and 5 teammembers in the CSV but in the loop it hits one where theres only 3 tasks and one or no teammembers. will it just put blanks for the rest? or will it error out? ill find out soon enough lol. THANKS! will report results.

Comment: well it almost worked perfectly!  I switched to fromstring since I'm doing all the gets and that in memory, not saving it as files.  But yeah if the task number or teammember items dont match up to the amount of fields "task1" "task2"  etc.. it starts writing the next line in the same row, so i ended up with a massssssive first row and no others.

Comment: I'm assuming its the count.... <= 3 for the three team members and 2 tasks.... there must be a dynamic way. if full_name == "" then break loop? not sure of syntax....

Comment: Which script version are you using? Can you update files with example of *don't match up to amount of fields*?

Comment: Updated with the actual data I'm using. I'm not pulling from the files though, this is all in memory when I'm running the script. I don't think that matters but.

Comment: hey Parfait, I tried all weekend but couldnt get this to work. So I'm trying to make it simpler. It's not preferred but if I can get the data it's fine. So I'm trying to just export the files separately. 2-3 files instead of one big one. I cant seem to save the joined Task/Team xml as a CSV no matter what I do. I've tried all day. I posted a new question here: 39094234.  Sorry I couldn't get your solution to work. I tried for hours. Thanks againn though for the time.